# Smoothly animate v-show in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I was trying to animated two divs using transition in Vuejs. Below is the code (jsfiddle) that I've used. But don't know why it's not working

https://jsfiddle.net/k6grqLh1/16/

vue

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-show="show">
        <div class="box yellow"></div>
      </div>
     </transition>
     <transition name="fade">
      <div v-show="!show">
        <div class="box blue"></div>
      </div>
      </transition>
    <a href="#" @click="show = !show">Change</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

css

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}

.box {
  width:200px;height:200px;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

js

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to add key in each of the div, besides adding vue 2.x in the fiddle, You need to make following changes:

**Why** from [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements)

> When toggling between elements that have the same tag name, you must tell Vue that they are distinct elements by giving them unique key attributes. Otherwise, Vue’s compiler will only replace the content of the element for efficiency. Even when technically unnecessary though, it’s considered good practice to always key multiple items within a  component.

**HTML**

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div key="3" v-if="show">
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
  </div>
</transition>
<transition name="fade">
  <div key="1" v-if="!show">
    <div class="box blue"></div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6grqLh1/21/

### Edited

To make it more smooth, you can use [Transition-Modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes): `mode="out-in"`, which will make the current element transitions out first, then when complete, the new element transitions in. see below code:

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div key="3" v-if="show">
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div key="1" v-if="!show">
    <div class="box blue"></div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6grqLh1/22/

Comment: @GijoVarghese so earlier there was no animation, Now it is not smooth as at the the time of transition there are two divs avaialble, there need to play some other CSS properties and how exactly it should be as you can not have one div top of another.

Comment: Isn't it possible in vuejs itself? Without using css keyframes?

Comment: @Saurabh You used in your code `v-if` instead of `v-show` is that suggested? Should I use v-if rather that v-show? (also if using v-if it's better `v-if='!value'` or `v-else`?

Comment: @Costantin check [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show) and [this](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/12/v-if-vs-v-show/3)

Comment: @Saurabh i don't think this works with v-show. [Transition can only hold single elements (will throw a warning in console)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6311#issuecomment-320715541) and this rule is broken when using v-show -> changing v-if to v-show does not transition smoothly like it does in v-if

Comment: The question is about `v-show` and you use `v-if`

Answer (score 2):

First of all.. you are importing Vue 1.
If you import Vue 2 this html works

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="show" key="yellow">
        <div class="box yellow"></div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="!show" key="blue">
        <div class="box blue"></div>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <a href="#" @click="show = !show">Change</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Then you should read the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements if you want to see how transitions between elements are handled

Comment: ok. I've updated it with vue 2. Still the animation is not smooth. Overlapping. Can you pls take a look at that jsfiddle again. I've updated it