# VueJS good practice: animation to show only one of a set of elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It may be most helpful if I describe my use-case; I want to create an input-widget that
depending on user-specified data may show a rather big number of checkboxes, that can roughly be divided into three parts.

My idea was to show these three subsections initially hidden, indicated by some header while a click on one of the headers would slide-in the actual content that would be loaded anyways so it is no "real" conditional rendering scenario. 
With this as basic setup I would want to hide an "opened" section when another sections header is clicked.

What came closest to giving me an idea how to solve my problem was this:

[Smoothly animate v-show in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019828/smoothly-animate-v-show-in-vuejs)

but I am not entirely sure what would be "good" or the "vue"-way for a non binary case. My idea similar to the answer in the mentioned question had been to use something like this as a status-indicator:

```
[...]
data:function(){
    return {
        sectionShowStatuses: {
            first: false,
            second: false,
            third: false
        }
    }
}
[...]
```

and then manipulate this status indication based on click on the section-headers and link the presence of css-classes on the elements to the status-information that handle smoothly animating a slide-in/out effect.

Would this be good practice or is there a more elegant/vue-esc way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd rethink this in terms of [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). It just seems like a better and cleaner way to handle what you're trying to achieve.

[Transitioning Between Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components)

Comment: Looks nice! Thanks :)